# Custom Class - have to use new rather than overwriting. Why?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, class

I have a custom Vector2 class and a variable named tempVect.

I reuse this throughout a game thread but originally I was just overwriting the new variables

```
    tempVect.x = blahhere;
tempVect.y = blahthere;
tempVect = conversion(tempVect); //this just changes the float to * 0.8

if(ball.velocity != tempVector)
    ball.velocity = tempVector;

tempVect.x = thisHere;
tempVect.y = thisThere;
tempVect = conversion(tempVect); 

if(ball.position != tempVector)
    ball.position = tempVector;

for(int i = 0; i < somevairablenum; i++)
{
    tempVect.x = anotherHere;
    tempVect.y = anotherThere;
    tempVect = conversion(tempVect); 
    player.position = tempVect;
}
```

The do somethings would conflict with each other whilst using the tempVect. (so the do something 2 would use the original blahHere and blahThere)

However I solved this by just doing

```
tempVect = new Vector2(blahHere, blahThere);

//do something

tempVect = new Vector2(thisHere, thisThere);

//do something different
```

Is anyone able to explain why this was the case? Unfortunately this is my university final project and so any problems I have I need to write down why they happened and how I resolved them, but I don't understand the theory behind this.

Can anyone else?

TIA

----- edit ------

The actual problem was the for loop, the player position was getting mixed up with the ball position.

Comment: My guess would be that the compiler didn't correctly see the dependencies and started pipelining in the wrong order.

Comment: It's not at all clear what the problem is.  Can you explain what you mean by "conflict with each other", perhaps with an example?  And tell us what "do something" does?

Comment: @bdares: This would not be my guess.

Comment: I've edited the code to give a better idea of what it was doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, each time you use 'tempVect', it references the same vector, hence the clash.
When you allocate a new vector you create a new object - the .x and .y members are distinct - they refer to a different object (i.e. a different set of variables).

So, even though you are using the 'tempVect' variable each time, 'tempVect' it a reference - and by using 'new' you make it reference different objects, so the assignments do not conflict - since they go to separate objects.

Comment: Thanks for this. I would have thought when I assign a new value to it, it would remove the old reference, but clearly keeps it there.

Comment: not if your conversion function returns a reference to the same object.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `!=` isn't what you want to compare those vectors - even if `x` and `y` are equal, if the vectors are distinct objects, `!=` will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you've left out the critical part - the content of the "do something"s.

However, most likely one of those "do somethings" was stashing a reference to your vector somewhere, and referring to its contents later. This would then result in it seeing the updated values when it later looks at the contents of the vector.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying to get away with not copying and pasting a lot of my code to make me look like a newbie. But I have put in what my code was doing. Thanks.